# Computing the identity using the change of basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

I was wondering what a good starting point was, since I wasn't given a vector to start out with.

Compute the Change of Basis Matrices for the following in polynomial space $\textbf{P}_3$:

$$\mathcal{E}: e_0=1,e_1=t,e_2=t^2,e_3=t^3$$
$$\mathcal{B}: b_0=1, b_1=(1+t),b_2=(1+t)^2,b_3=(1+t)^3$$
Compute $[\mathrm{id}]_{\mathcal{B} \leftarrow \mathcal {E}}$

Comment: Don't let the fact that they're polynomials fool you, all that matters is the coefficients. As vector spaces the only difference between $t^n$ and $t_n$ is notation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal E=\{1,t,t^2,t^3\}$ and $\mathcal B=\{1,1+t,(1+t)^2,(1+t)^3\}$ be two basis for $\mathbb{R[x]_{\le3}}$.
We want to find $\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal E}^{\mathcal B}(id):$
$e_0=b_0$; $e_1=b_1-b_0$; $e_2=b_2-2b_1+b_0$ and $e_3=b_3-3b_2-3b_1+5b_0$ so
$$\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal E}^{\mathcal B}(id)=\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 &  5\\
0 & 1  & -2 & -3 \\
0 & 0  & 1  & -3  \\
0 & 0  & 0  & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
$$
The columns of the matrix represent the linear combination of $b_0,b_1,b_2$ and $b_3 $ to express the vector of the canonical basis.